# I am trying to junit test repository , getting null pointer exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, spring-repositories

**THIS IS THE CODE**
***I WANT TO WRITE JUNITS FOR REPOSITORYY, AND TEST findByName() method***

```
   public interface CodeRepository extends JpaRepository<CodeEntity, Integer> {

    
    CodeEntity findByCode(String code);

    CodeEntity findByCodeIgnoreCaseAndCodeType(String code, String codeType);
}
```

## I wrote junit test case for this

```
   @DataJpaTest
   public class CodeRepositoryTest {
   
    @Autowired
    CodeRepository codeRepository;

    final TestData testData = new TestData();

    @Test
    public void testRepository() {
    final CodeEntity codeEntity = testData.getCodeEntity(); //codeEntity is not null
    codeRepository.save(codeEntity);   //here i am getting null pointer exception
```

***STACK TRACE***

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.oversighttech.ocr.dao.repository.CodeRepositoryTest.testRepository(CodeRepositoryTest.java:29)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)

Comment: Can you paste the actual error you get?

Comment: You are not supposed to use `@DataJpaTest` and `@SpringBootTest` together - they both set up spring context (with different slices of the app) - use only one. For the NPE - please post entire stack trace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I removed @SpringBootTest still getting the same error

Comment: So if there is an NPE at that point, the immediate cause is that `codeRepository` is `null`.  In other words, it has not been (successfully) autowired.